# Why am I getting 403 error in scraping using scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

**I am getting the following error even though I have seen many qustions related to 403 forbidden in scrapy and changed according to those answer.**

I have changed the user-agents as well as rotated those agents as well. I am running the script as **./run.sh 16816** 

Is there any way to not get 403 forbidden error? Can anyone help me through this?

```
`2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: lead_scraper)
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 
  1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
  - [GCC 8.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux- 
  5.0.0-1027-azure-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 3, 'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 0.5, 'BOT_NAME': 'lead_scraper', 
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5, 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': 
 ['name', 'category', 'postal_code', 'location', 'phone_1', 'phone_2', 'website', 'email'], 
 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_URI': 'output/bsg-16816.csv', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 
 'lead_scraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['lead_scraper.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 
 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1'}
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 9ad2a66ce7bb22e5
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
 ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.spiderstate.SpiderState',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled SeleniumMiddleware: SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME 
  and SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH must be set
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
 ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
 ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
 []
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 
  items (at 0 items/min)
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [py.warnings] WARNING: /home/anand/lead-scraper/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
  packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py:61: URLWarning: allowed_domains accepts only domains, 
  not URLs. Ignoring URL entry https://www.11880.com in allowed_domains.
  warnings.warn(message, URLWarning)
 2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
 **2019-12-17 15:29:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.11880.com/> 
 (referer: None)**
 2019-12-17 15:29:39 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 
 'www.11880.com': <POST https://www.11880.com/ajax/getsuggestedcities>
 2019-12-17 15:29:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
 2019-12-17 15:29:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
 {'downloader/request_bytes': 313,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 104606,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.201476,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 15, 29, 39, 86775),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'memusage/max': 54697984,
 'memusage/startup': 54697984,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 1,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 15, 29, 38, 885299)}
 2019-12-17 15:29:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)`
```

**I have scraper as eleveneighteighty.py**

```
`import json
 from scrapy import Spider, FormRequest, Request

 def clean_text(text):
    text = text.strip().replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").replace("\xa0", "")
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text


 class ElevenEightEightySpider(Spider):
    name = 'ElevenEightEightySpider'
    allowed_domains = ['11880.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.11880.com/telefonbuch']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [403]
    used_phones = set()
    locations = set()

  def __init__(self, zipcode='', domain=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.domain = domain
    self.zipcodes = zipcode.split(",")
    # self.zipcodes = ['16816']

def parse(self, response):
    for zipcode in self.zipcodes:
        yield FormRequest("https://www.11880.com/ajax/citySuggest", formdata={
            "zipCity": zipcode,
            "searchType": "cityExtSuggest",
            "street": ""
        }, headers={
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }, callback=self.parse_locations)

def parse_locations(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    selected_locations = set()
    for location in jsonresponse['locations']:
        selected_locations.add(location['citySlug'])
    for selected_location in selected_locations:
        yield Request("https://www.11880.com/suche/-/{}".format(selected_location), self.parse_list,
                      meta={
                          'location': selected_location,
                          'page': 1
                      })

def parse_list(self, response):
    location = response.meta['location']
    page = int(response.meta['page'])
    hit_count = response.css('#hit-count::text').extract_first() or 0
    if hit_count == 0:
        return None
    result_items = response.css('ol.search-result-list li.search-result-list-item')
    for result_item in result_items:
        if result_item.css('.result-entry-regio-header'):
            continue
        item = {}
        name = result_item.css('h2[itemprop=name]::text').extract_first() or ''

        if not name:
            continue
        item['name'] = clean_text(name)
        if result_item.css('a[itemprop=url]'):
            item['url'] = "https://www.11880.com" + result_item.css('a[itemprop=url]::attr(href)').extract_first()
        else:
            item['source'] = result_item.css('input[name=source]::attr(value)').extract_first()
            item['url'] = "https://www.11880.com/form?id" + item['source']
        item['category'] = clean_text(result_item.css('.category-primary-trade::text').extract_first() or '')
        item['secondary_category'] = clean_text(
            result_item.css('.category-secondary-trades::text').extract_first() or '')
        item['distance'] = result_item.css('span.distance::text').extract_first()
        item['location'] = location
        url = item['url']
        if item.get('source') is None:
            r = Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)
        else:
            formdata = {
                'source': item['source']
            }
            r = FormRequest(url, callback=self.parse_item, formdata=formdata)
        r.meta['item'] = item
        yield r
    next_source = response.css('div.next form.link-form input[name="source"]::attr(value)').extract_first() or ''
    if next_source:
        formdata = {
            'source': next_source
        }
        r = FormRequest('https://www.11880.com/form', callback=self.parse_list, formdata=formdata)
        r.meta['location'] = location
        r.meta['page'] = page
        yield r

def parse_item(self, response):
    if "person" in response.url:
        return None
    item = response.meta['item']

    item['etype'] = response.css('.entry-detail__title--type span::text').extract_first()
    if item['etype'] == 'Personen-Eintrag':
        return None
    item['description'] = clean_text(response.css('.entry-item .description::text').extract_first() or '')
    item['postalCode'] = clean_text(response.css('span[itemprop=postalCode]::text').extract_first() or '')
    item['addressLocality'] = clean_text(response.css('span[itemprop=addressLocality]::text').extract_first() or '')
    item['addressRegion'] = clean_text(response.css('span[itemprop=addressRegion]::text').extract_first() or '')
    item['addressCountry'] = clean_text(
        response.css('meta[itemprop=addressCountry]::attr(content)').extract_first() or '')
    item['phone'] = [clean_text(x) for x in response.css('span[itemprop=telephone]::text').extract()]
    for i in range(0, min(5, len(item['phone']))):
        item['phone%d' % (i + 1)] = item['phone'][i]
    if item['phone']:
        if item['phone'][0] in self.used_phones:
            return None
        else:
            self.used_phones.add(item['phone'][0])
    item['faxNumber'] = [clean_text(x) for x in response.css('span[itemprop=faxNumber]::text').extract()]
    item['email'] = [clean_text(x) for x in response.css('.web-soc meta[itemprop=email]::attr(content)').extract()]
    item['website'] = [clean_text(x) for x in response.css('.web-soc meta[itemprop=url]::attr(content)').extract()]
    item['facebook'] = [x for x in response.css('.web-soc a.box-facebook::attr(href)').extract()]
    item['google'] = [x for x in response.css('.web-soc a.box-google::attr(href)').extract()]
    item['about'] = "\n".join([x for x in response.css('#about .distances::text').extract()])
    item['tags'] = [clean_text(x) for x in
                    response.css('#about .branch-and-search .trades-list li a::text').extract()]
    item['schedule'] = []
    for t in response.css('#opening-hours .openingHourRow'):
        d = clean_text(t.css('div.week-days::text').extract_first() or '')
        h = clean_text(t.css('div.hours1::text').extract_first() or '')
        if d:
            item['schedule'].append((d, h))
    yield item`
```

**I have the following as setting.py**

```
`# Custom settings
 FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ['name', 'category', 'postal_code', 'location', 'phone_1', 'phone_2', 
 'website', 'email']

 # Scrapy settings for lead_scraper project
 #
 # For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
 # commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
 #
 #     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
 #     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
 #     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

 BOT_NAME = 'lead_scraper'

 SPIDER_MODULES = ['lead_scraper.spiders']
 NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'lead_scraper.spiders'

 # Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
 #USER_AGENT = 'lead_scraper (https://www.11880.com/telefonbuch)'
 #USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
 #USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
 USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1"
 # Obey robots.txt rules
 ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

 # Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
 CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

 # Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
 # See also autothrottle settings and docs
 DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
 # The download delay setting will honor only one of:
 #CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
 #CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 1

 # Disable cookies (enabled by default)
 COOKIES_ENABLED = False

 # Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
 #TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

 # Override the default request headers:
 DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'Accept-Language': 'en',
 'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1'
 }

 # File exporter
 FEED_EXPORTERS = {
 'csv': 'lead_scraper.middlewares.MyProjectCsvItemExporter',
 }
 CSV_DELIMITER = ";"

 # Enable or disable spider middlewares
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
 #SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
 #    'lead_scraper.middlewares.LeadScraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
 #}

 # Enable or disable downloader middlewares
 #PROXY_POOL_ENABLED = True
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
 DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
 # 'lead_scraper.middlewares.LeadScraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
 'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
 #  'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
 # 'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
 }

 # Enable or disable extensions
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
 #EXTENSIONS = {
 #    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
 #}

 # Configure item pipelines
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
 #ITEM_PIPELINES = {
 #    'lead_scraper.pipelines.LeadScraperPipeline': 300,
 #}

 # Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
 # See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
 AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
 # The initial download delay
 AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 3
 # The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
 AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
 # The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
 # each remote server
 AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 0.5
 # Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
 #AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

 # Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
 # See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
 #HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
 #HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
 #HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
 #HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
 #HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'`
```

Comment: You very probably got blacklisted, and if you're scrapping a site without regards to their policy and robots.txt that's actually what you deserve.

Comment: if you blocked then you may have to use proxy servers (free or paid) to get this page.